# Prolog Rules in example

Tags: prolog

I have a database in Prolog like this:

```
connection(a,b,bus)
connection(b,c,metro)
connection(b,d,taxi)
connection(d,e,bus)
```

What I want is the rules I need to apply so I can ask the question: "transport(a,c)" and it answers: "bus" and "metro"

Is that possible to define 1 or 2 rules so that the query "transport(a,c)" works ?

you should see the database like:

`connection(Departure,Arrive,Transport).` 
so that... `connection(D,A,T).`

then the rules are:

```
connection(D,A,T):- traject(D,A,T). 
connection(D,A,T):- traject(D,X,T1), traject(X,A,T2).
```

where...`traject(Departure, X, Transport1)` and `traject(X, Arrival, Transport2)`

and the query should be something like:

`transport(a,c,T1).` and 
`transport(a,c,T2).`

and then the answer should come:

```
T1 = bus 
T2 = metro
```

Comment: Yes, it possible to define such rules. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm quite new in Prolog, but I've tried something like: connect(D,A,T):- traject(D,A,T).
connect(D,A,T):- traject(D,X,T1), traject(X,A,T2). but that the query didn't work after it... :S

Comment: You should add the code you tried to your question. And you need to show the definition of `traject/3`.

Comment: you should see the database like: connection(Departure,Arrive,Transport).  so that... connection(D,A,T).
then the rules are: 
connect(D,A,T):- traject(D,A,T). 
connect(D,A,T):- traject(D,X,T1), traject(X,A,T2).

traject(Departure, X, Transport1)
traject(X, Arrival, Transport2)

and the query should be something like:
transport(a,c,T1).
and
transport(a,c,T2).

and then the answer should come:
T1 = bus
T2 = metro

Comment: You need to add relevant code to your question by editing it. It's difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: I edited my question already. What I put there is something that I've tried but it's not working like it is right now...I need help to figure out maybe a diferent rule or diferent question to make me get the answer I just examplified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
transport(A, B, [Method]) :- connection(A, B, Method).
transport(A, C, [Method|Others]) :-
    connection(A, B, Method),
    transport(B, C, Others).
```

The base case here is that you have a direct connection. The inductive case is to find a connection and then recur from the intermediate. Note that you will get an infinite regress if you try using `transport/3` twice in the body instead of `connection/3` and then `transport/3`! Try it and see!

This seems to work for the inputs I expect:

```
?- transport(a, c, M).
M = [bus, metro] ;
false.

?- transport(a, d, M).
M = [bus, taxi] ;
false.

?- transport(a, e, M).
M = [bus, taxi, bus] ;
false.
```

Hope this helps!