# Prolog Recursive example

Tags: prolog

I have this database in Prolog:

```
connection(a,b,bus).
connection(b,c,metro).
connection(b,d,taxi).
connection(d,e,bus).
```

How can I set the rules so the question: `trajectbetween(a,c,T).` gives me back the answer: `T = b`

I've tried the rule:

```
traject(A, B):- connection(A, X,_), traject(X,B).
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have a base case for `traject/2`. If every case must recur, how does the predicate ever succeed?

Answering your question to the letter I think produces this:

```
trajectbetween(A,C,X) :- connection(A,X,_), connection(X,C,_).
```

Note there is no recursion here, so this will generate, at best, one-stop solutions. If you want other solutions it probably will not be sufficient; you may want to try something like what you have as the second case.

Again, please [review my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989807/prolog-rules-in-example/33993084#33993084) as it may be helpful.